# Player can see behind themselves in Canvas-based JavaScript 3D Engine

Tags: javascript, html, 3d

I am building a 3D Engine with JavaScript and I'm running into a problem. The engine can't tell if a point is behind the camera, and projects the 3D points to 2D regardless, creating weird artifacts when you go down this hallway demo scene. It allows the player to see behind themselves, which obviously can't be in the engine.

I have been tinkering with this problem for 2 days, and still haven't found a fix. Can anyone help?

Here's the code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Triangles!</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="./main.js" async defer></script>
    <canvas id="gl"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
// Global Constants

const canvas = document.getElementById('gl');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Global Variables

let mouseX;
let mouseY;
let delta = 0;
let fov = 300;
let cameraX = 0;
let cameraY = -50;
let cameraZ = 500;
let screenX;
let screenY;
let fps;

// Classes

// Point3D Class: The basis of it all. Defines a point in our 3D World.
class Point3D {
    constructor (x, y, z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}

class Point2D {
    constructor (x, y, outOfView) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.outOfView = outOfView;
    }
}

// Global Arrays

// vertices3D[] - discribes the points on screen using arrays of the Point3D class.
// Example: let vertices = [[new Point3D(0, 0, 0), new Point3D(0, 10, 0), new Point3D(10, 0, 0)]] would define a triangle, as the subarray has 3 point3Ds, which would imply a triangle in 3D space.

let vertices3D = [[new Point3D(-100, 0, 400), new Point3D(-100, 0, 0), new Point3D(-100, -100, 400)], [new Point3D(-100, -100, 400), new Point3D(-100, -100, 0), new Point3D(-100, 0, 0)], [new Point3D(100, 0, 400), new Point3D(100, 0, 0), new Point3D(100, -100, 400)], [new Point3D(100, -100, 400), new Point3D(100, -100, 0), new Point3D(100, 0, 0)]];
let vertices2D = [];

// times[] - used in the FPS measurement script. No idea what it does, I stole it from StackOverflow.

let times = [];

// Functions

// The function for basic 3D projection onto a 2D surface. Does not include rotation.

let projectPoint = (point) => {
    return new Point2D((point['x']-cameraX)*(fov/(point['z']-cameraZ)), (point['y']-cameraY)*(fov/(point['z']-cameraZ)), (point.z > cameraZ));
}

let projectAll3DVerts = () => {
    vertices2D = [];
    for (i = 0; i < vertices3D.length; i++) {
        vertices2D.push([]);
        for (j = 0; j < vertices3D[i].length; j++) {
            vertices2D[vertices2D.length-1].push(projectPoint(vertices3D[i][j]));
        }
    }
}

let renderVerts = () => {
    for (i = 0; i < vertices2D.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < vertices2D[i].length; j++) {
            if (j === 0) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(vertices2D[i][j].x, vertices2D[i][j].y);
            } else {
                ctx.lineTo(vertices2D[i][j].x, vertices2D[i][j].y);
            }
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

let init = () => {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    // Translates the canvas origin to an objectively better point. 
    ctx.translate(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.font = '20px monospace';
}

let frame = () => {
    ctx.clearRect(-window.innerWidth/2, -window.innerHeight/2, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    delta++;
    cameraZ--;
    projectAll3DVerts();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    renderVerts();
    const now = performance.now();
    while (times.length > 0 && times[0] <= now - 1000) {
      times.shift();
    }
    times.push(now);
    fps = times.length;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText('FPS: '+fps+' Camera Z: '+cameraZ, (-window.innerWidth/2)+5, (-window.innerHeight/2)+15);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {frame()});
}

// Event Listeners

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    mouseX = event.clientX-window.innerWidth/2;
    mouseY = event.clientY-window.innerHeight/2;
});

// Initialization & Main Loop
init();
frame();
```

style.css:

```
html, body, div, canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```